# Is there a way to clear the colour from the memory of LWJGL?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am creating a 2D game where I am currently drawing on the screen, a quad filling the entire screen to have a blue background.  Then I am drawing a stone texture on top of it.  The issue is when the program draws the stone, it gives it a blue tint as it is using the colour from the sky quad.  I was wondering if there is a way to clear the colour from the memory of OpenGL / GLFW / LWJGL.  I am using Java 1.8 and LWJGL 3.2.3

Here is the code:

```
private static void renderAir() {
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(InnocentDream.win);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor4f(0, 204 / 255f, 1, 1);
        glVertex2f(-256, 128);
        glColor4f(0, 204 / 255f, 1, 1);
        glVertex2f(256, 128);
        glColor4f(0, 108 / 255f, 250 / 255f, 1);
        glVertex2f(256, -128);
        glColor4f(0, 108 / 255f, 250 / 255f, 1);
        glVertex2f(-256, -128);
        glEnd();
}
```

I have the `GLFW` and `GL11` classes as static imports.

```
public void renderTileAtPos(float x, float y) {
        float TILE_WIDTH = Tile.TILE_WIDTH / 2f;
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getTextureID());
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2f(-TILE_WIDTH + x, TILE_WIDTH + y);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(TILE_WIDTH + x, TILE_WIDTH + y);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2f(TILE_WIDTH + x, -TILE_WIDTH + y);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2f(-TILE_WIDTH + x, -TILE_WIDTH + y);
        glEnd();
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

And here is the tile rendering.

Comment: It is worth mentioning at this point, that the method of rendering you are using dates back over 30 years now with the original IRIS GL (the ancestor of OpenGL), and was made obsolete with OpenGL 1.1. While it works just fine, there are very large performance gains from using vertex buffers, and all the other modern trappings. Windows and Linux don't care, MacOS requires you to pick either old OpenGL or modern GL3, it will not allow you to mix and match. You can enforce these modes on Windows and Linux if you're worried about MacOS compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
glColor4f(1,1,1,1);
```

Throw that call either after your original sky code, or just before you render the stone.

It's a good practice if using `glColor()` calls, to get in the habit of *always* calling `glColor()` before drawing anything, or to only call it once on initialisation and never call it again.

There is no "remove the colour I just set" call. The value of "glColor" is just one of those pieces of state that OpenGL hangs on to.